# Avoid SIGKILL with PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pycharm, ubuntu-18.04

I have a simple loop to plot some accumulating values in some simulation that takes a long time to compute. I reduced it to following MCVE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

counter = 0
yvalues = [0]
for k in range(1000):
    for l in range(10_000_000):
        counter += 1 + np.tanh(counter)
        print(k, l, counter)
    yvalues.append(counter)
    plt.plot(yvalues)
    plt.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

The problem is that after a while I get a notification that "PyCharm is not responding", even though the program is still running and working perfectly well.

[image]

The message alone is not the problem yet, but if you just ignore this warning and do not press *Wait* the program will stop and display

```
Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

(The same thing happens when you just press *Force Quit*.)

**Does anyone know why this is happening and how to avoid it?**

It makes it impossible to run this simulation e.g. overnight as you constantly have to look out for this warning and press *Wait* again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732683/python-sigkill-catching-strategies

Comment: @CarlosGonzalez thanks for the link! Actually I'd like to avoid getting a *SIGKILL* in the first place - I just don't know why I am getting it and what I could do to avoid it. (I have the impression that it might have something to do with the `matplotlib`-plot, but I have no idea what exactly is the issue.)

Comment: That this issue also appear when you run it in the terminal and not in PyCharm?

Comment: I just tried that and the plot window doesn't even show up. It does show up however if we append  a `plt.pause(0.01)` after, but then we get a similar message *matplotlib is not responding*.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the linked question in @CarlosGonzalez's comment, SIGKILL may be sent by the Linux OOM (out-of-memory) killer. If this is the case, then the only solution is to use less memory, or obtain more memory.

Given how long it takes to run your MCVE, I am unable to determine the exact source that is using so much memory, but I can guess that it is unrelated to the `counter` or `yvalues` --- `counter` is at most on the order of magnitude 10^10 (1000 * 10_000_000), which fits in a 64-bit integer fine (8 bytes of memory), and `yvalues` can hold 1000 of those fine too (using 8kB if we suppose it's an array and `counter` is a 64-bit int).

With the following code, I note that `fig.canvas.flush_events()` runs rather slowly compared to the rest of the code (try commenting it out and comparing the speed, and note how Ctrl-C/SIGINT fails to stop it):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
counter = 0
yvalues = [0]
for k in range(1000):
    counter += 1e7
    yvalues.append(counter)
    plt.plot(yvalues)
    plt.draw()
    print(k)
    fig.canvas.flush_events()  # Potentially problematic?
```

Perhaps you might need to reconsider your need to flush the canvas events.