# How to send SIGINT to python running in a subprocess

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I have a python program that runs another python script in a subprocess (yes I know this architecture is not ideal but the nature of the project makes it necessary). I am trying to:

**1. send a sigint to the python subprocess (simulate a keyboard kill)**

**2. catch the sigint in the subprocess and perform some cleanup before exit**

The code follows this general pattern:

A.py

```
import signal
import subprocess
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen('python B.py', shell=True)
time.sleep(1)
proc.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

B.py

```
try:
  while True:
    # some application logic
    pass
except:
  # some cleanup logic
  print('bye')
```

**But when I run A.py, B.py never receives the signal or does it's cleanup logic. Any idea what is going on here?**

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732683/python-sigkill-catching-strategies)?

Comment: no that question seems to be about force killing (signal 9). I need to send signal 2 and catch it in the child process

Comment: `shell=True` means the chilld process is a shell and the python is the grandchild.  https://bugs.python.org/issue4855

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.8/bin/python3

import signal
import subprocess
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'B.py'], shell=False)
time.sleep(1)
proc.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
proc.wait()
```

...as your A.py?

I suspect the shell is ignoring SIGINT rather than passing it down to B.py.

Comment: Shells never forward signals so this is the right approach

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment below, I launched a Kubuntu VM and it works if you specify `bash` to be used and `shell=False`. The reason is given in the comment, but `/bin/sh` is aliased to `dash` on Debain/Ubuntu (perhaps other distros as well). To determine what your system uses, open a terminal and type `ls -l /bin/sh`.

A.py

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', 'python3 B.py'], shell=False)
```

I ran the file with `python3 A.py`. Version: Python 3.6.7.

**Prior Answer**

It works for me. My thought is perhaps you need to use `python3` in your string.

I'm on Arch Linux and `python` is actually `python3`.

Here is what I have.

A.py

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen('python B.py', shell=True)
time.sleep(1)
proc.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

B.py

```py
import time

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.25)
        print('running B')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('bye')
```

Output:

```sh
running B
running B
running B
bye
```

Comment: This works on systems where `sh` is `bash`, because bash has a tail call optimization in which it tries to avoid forking on its final command. It will fail on e.g. Debian where `sh` is `dash`.

Comment: I updated answer. And tested in on kubuntu, which has `/bin/sh` aliased to `dash`. [This also seems useful to know](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138509/why-does-bash-c-somecommand-sometimes-not-leave-a-bash-process/138510#138510), even though I don't understand it in its entirety.