# Do an action if the server is killed or interrupted with CTRL+C or crashed

Tags: python, flask, atexit

I have an app running constantly (started in Linux with `screen -S myapp python3 app.py` and then I detach it). It could be a Bottle app, Flask app, or any other system involving a forever-running event loop:

```
import anyframework   # can be bottle, flask or anything else
import sqlite3

@route('/')
def index():
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?)', ('test',))
    c.close()  # we can't commit here for *each* client request, it would eat 100ms for each request
    return 'hello'

@route('/makeitcrash')
def index():
    sdlfksdfs  # this will generate an error

def cleanup():
    db.commit()

db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
run()
```

**How to make sure reliably that `cleanup()` (and thus DB commit) is called in all possible cases of the server terminating?** i.e.:

- if the server is killed with SIGKILL, SIGTERM
- if the server code has an error (exemple if http://example.com/makeitcrash is visited)
- if I do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal (inside the running `screen`)

?

I was about to use `atexit` and to add `try: except:` everywhere but I think it would introduce many code duplication to insert `try: except:` for every route.

What is the general solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to catch signals and do cleanup when one is received.

```
import signal
import sys

from bottle import run

def handle_signal(signum, frame):
    print(f'handling signal {signum}')
    # do cleanup
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_signal)
# also SIGTERM, et al.

run()
```

**Caveats**

As @MarkAllen points out, `SIGKILL` can never be caught.

I also would advise against approaching the problem this way in the first place. Instead, see if you can design your web app so that it doesn't need to do any cleanup on shutdown. (For example, perform a durable write on each request, instead of buffering in memory.) Reducing the amount of state that you keep around will help simplify many things, including how to handle crashes/shutdowns.

Answer (score 0):

"SIGKILL by its very nature cannot be trapped."

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30732799/7527728

You could possibly use a with statement for the cases which can be trapped, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/

There's a very simple example of how to define **enter** and **exit** blocks here: https://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: Thanks. In my example code, where would you set the `with`? (Could you maybe post an example code?)

Comment: hey, I edited the answer with a link that has a simple example, it should be clear from there what you need to do, otherwise let me know :)

Comment: Thanks  @MarkAllen for your edit. I already know `with` in various cases (mostly for file open, etc.) but in this precise case here with Bottle or Flask, how would you use it? (some sample code would be help for this context)